# Multiply two arrays element wise, where one of the arrays has arrays as elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following situation in which I want to multiply two arrays element wise, where one of the arrays has arrays as elements:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> base = np.array( [100., 111.,] )
>>> c = np.array( [9., 11.] )
>>> n0 = np.zeros(len(base))
>>> nn = 3 + n0     # This is the gist of a bunch of intermediate operations
>>> grid = [np.ones(i) for i in nn]
>>> base
array([ 100.,  111.])
>>> c
array([  9.,  11.])
>>> nn
array([ 3.,  3.])
>>> grid
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

So far everything looks good. `grid` seems to have two elements, three elements long each. I feel I should be able to multiply it with `c`

```
>>> a = grid * c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2)
```

That does not go as I had hoped for. The error is promising. I can do some transposition tricks and get my result:

> > > a = (grid.T * c).T
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >           AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'

That fails more espectacularly than I expected. I thought I was working with an array, but I learn that I now have a list. I try my hand at some good old fashioned brute force:

```
>>> grid_mod = np.array( [np.ones(3), np.ones(3) ] )
>>> grid_mod
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> grid_mod * c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2)
```

I was sure that would work! I notice an extraneous space after my last element, so I remove it:

```
>>> grid_mod2 = np.array( [np.ones(3), np.ones(7)] )
>>> grid_mod2
array([array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])], dtype=object)
>>> grid_mod2 * c
array([array([ 9.,  9.,  9.]),
       array([ 11.,  11.,  11.,  11.,  11.,  11.,  11.])], dtype=object)
```

That last one works as expected.

My questions are:

1. How can I define `grid` so that the result is an array of arrays instead of a list of arrays.
2. What is actually going on in all of this? Why does the extra space at the end of the array give me a completely different result.
3. Is there a more pythonic way of going about this?

Comment: try to use `grid=np.vstack(grid)` and use the 2-D array `grid`

Comment: This still gives me a broadcasting error when I do the multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two pieces of code produce different things, although the space has no effect:

```
>>> np.array([np.ones(3), np.ones(3)])
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Because both arrays in your list have the same dimension, this is converted into a single array of 2 rows and 3 columns.

```
>>> np.array([np.ones(3), np.ones(7)])
array([array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])], dtype=object)
```

In this case, the lengths of the arrays do not match, so numpy creates a 1D array, two items long, of type `object` and each of those objects happens to be a numpy array.

When you multiply the first with `c`, you are trying to multiply an array of shape `(2, 3)` with an array of shape `(2,)`, something numpy does not know how to do. You could get what you want if you reshaped your `c` array to have shape `(2, 1)`, e.g.

```
>>> grid_mod * c[:, np.newaxis]
array([[  9.,   9.,   9.],
       [ 11.,  11.,  11.]])
```

When you multiply the second with `c`, you are trying to multiply two arrays of shape `(2,)`, so numpy does elementwise multiplication with no problems. And since each of the items of your array is itself an array, when you try to multiply it by a scalar, numpy also know how to do it. While this does work, it is much, much slower than the previous approach, about 100x for 10000 row arrays:

```
c = np.random.rand(10000)
a = np.random.rand(10000, 3)
b = np.empty((10000,), dtype=object)
for j in xrange(10000):
    b[j] = a[j]

%timeit a*c[:, np.newaxis]
10000 loops, best of 3: 176 us per loop

%timeit b*c
10 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! This will hopefully do the trick for now. I read up a bit on `newaxis` and, while still fuzzy, it works for all cases I can think of right now. At this stage I am not looking at all into performance, but the performance difference between the two approaches is astounding. Thanks again!